# C++, Windows Phone 8 and the accelerometer

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, accelerometer

I am starting a new C++ project for Windows Phone. Does anyone know where I can find the library that gives me access to accelerometer data?

I was looking at this sample but I can't find a reference to the Ameter anywhere:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Marble-Maze-sample-for-c9f3706b/sourcecode?fileId=70045&pathId=1846009596

Edit::

Ah, 
using Windows::Devices::Sensors::Accelerometer

I am now using it like this but it's just not working as the AccelerometerReading is never allocated to memory:

**AccelerometerDelegate.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "pch.h"

using Windows::Devices::Sensors::AccelerometerReading;

class AccelerometerDelegate
{
public:
    double GetX();
    double GetY();
    double GetZ();
private:
    AccelerometerReading ^ accelerometerReading;
};
```

**AccelerometerDelegate.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "AccelerometerDelegate.h"

double AccelerometerDelegate::GetX()
{
    return this->accelerometerReading->AccelerationX;
}

double AccelerometerDelegate::GetY()
{
    return this->accelerometerReading->AccelerationY;
}

double AccelerometerDelegate::GetZ()
{
    return this->accelerometerReading->AccelerationZ;
}
```

Comment: I went for a C++ native app... from the windows phone new project creator. Direct3D Native only... My experience is good old C++ for desktop applications so I have never used the CLI syntax

Comment: I am a newbie btw... so really unsure of where to start with getting access to the accelerometer

Comment: What do you suggest me coding this in? Should I be doing this in C++?

Comment: You linked to C++/CLI code but tagged the question C++. I just wanted to verify whether the tag is correct.

Comment: ah, yes C++. I am struggling to find good examples but while awaiting responses, I'm watching this video hehe http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wiV_WVymHFk

Comment: I sussed it out... yay